# Getting an including classes name in the included module (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to use reflection in a module to map a class name to some data. My issue is that I can't always rely on using `self.class.name` in the module, since for subclasses it will give me the subclass's name. Is there a way for me to see the name of the class that is including the module?

```
class A
  include Mod
end

class B < A
end

module Mod
 MAP = { A: 1 }

  def map
    MAP[self.class.name.to_sym]
  end 
end

b = B.new
b.map        # => nil
```

Comment: You might check the "includer" class ancestors `MAP[self.class.ancestors[1].name.to_sym]`.

Comment: Also maybe look at the [`Module#included`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Module.html#method-i-included) hook.

Comment: @engineersmnky how would `#included` help me? Are you suggesting that I store the including class's name in a variable?